# Eslint glob (**) is not considering all directories recursively

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint

I am using OSX, in my `package.json` file I have the script entry:

`"lint": "eslint ./src/**/*.js"`

However, when I run `npm lint` only the 1st level of directories are being considered for linting, eg. `./src/dir/*` not `./src/dir/nested_dir/*`.

I was under the impression that `**` glob indicated recursive search?

Does anyone know how I can make this behave as expected?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The problem is likely missing quotes around the glob path.

Change this (not working):  `"lint": "eslint ./src/**/*.js"`

To this (working): `"lint": "eslint './src/**/*.js'"`

[The ESLint docs say this](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#run-the-cli):

> Please note that when passing a glob as a parameter, it is expanded by your shell. The results of the expansion can vary depending on your shell, and its configuration. If you want to use node glob syntax, you have to quote your parameter (using double quotes if you need it to run in Windows)

And some Googling turned up [this thread](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9330) on GitHub:

Comment: This works on macOS but when I tried it on Windows it failed. This seemed to be fine on both macOS and Windows. `"lint": "eslint \"./src/**/*.js\""`

Comment: doesn't work for me. goes only one level deep on linux

Comment: Works on Windows and Linux for me

Comment: That was it! My GitLab linting was complaining while local was fine (ignoring one file) adding the single quote made it consistent

Answer (score 21):

Try this instead:

```
"lint": "eslint src --ext .js"
```

Or for more than one extension:

```
"lint": "eslint src --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
```

See more info on [eslint's docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#-ext)

Comment: 2nd one did that!

Answer (score 0):

This command is working recursively in monorepos (first glob is for all subfolders in packages, second one, is for any subfolder in src). Without second glob, the command does not work.

```
"lint": "eslint 'packages/**/src/**' --ext .ts,.tsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

This also occurs when linting using `vue-cli-service` so you will need quotes with it as well:

```
"lint": "vue-cli-service lint './src/main/app/**/*.ts' './src/main/app/**/*.vue'"
```